# UWP Restart when closed by user

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a uwp app that launches an external application (Notepad). I want to make it so that when the user closes the Notepad app by clicking the red x button in the top-right corner, Notepad restarts itself. Is this even possible and if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restart the application on exit, you can take advantage of the `confirmAppClose` capability. When you capture the close event, you can launch the app and then finish closing the current instance. Keep in mind this is a restricted capability and will require special approval from Microsoft to submit to the Microsoft Store.